# vb Script and single quotes Can someone look at my code?

Tags: vba, vbscript

I am obviously doing something wrong here.  I need to know how single quotes should be treated.  I have the following sql code that does not run:

```
sql = "Select C.ID, cc.contact_email as Email, cc.web_user_id from customer c
Inner join CUSTOMER_CONTACT cc ON "

sql = sql & "c.ID = cc.customer_ID Where cc.web_user_id like "' %O%"'" 
and  c.ID like "' & CUSTID & "'" "
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  I saw lots of stuff on the web about what to do with double quotes and nothing on single quotes.

Comment: Not sure if the final Like needs a wildcard? dim sql sql = "Select C.ID, cc.contact_email as Email, cc.web_user_id from customer c Inner join CUSTOMER_CONTACT cc ON " 
sql = sql & "c.ID = cc.customer_ID Where cc.web_user_id like '%O%' and c.ID like 'CUSTID'"
msgbox sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sql = "SELECT C.ID, cc.contact_email as Email, cc.web_user_id " & _ 
      " FROM customer c Inner join CUSTOMER_CONTACT cc ON c.ID = cc.customer_ID " & _ 
      " WHERE cc.web_user_id like '%O%' and c.ID like '" & CUSTID & "' "
```

Let's see a simple sample of the process. We start with a sql command that will include data from a variable

```
select * from tblData where name='variable'
```

First step, quote the command and assign to a variable

```
sql = "select * from tblData where name='variable'"
```

Second step, cut where the variable needs to be inserted. Single quotes are not in the variable (for this sample) so they are keep in the string

```
sql = "select * from tblData where name='" | "'"
```

Third step, concatenate the variable contents in the cut place

```
sql = "select * from tblData where name='" & variable & "'"
```